Can I style a checkbox with unicode chars w/o using ::before and ::after?
I'd like to replace the content of my checkbox with the unicode checkbox marks. But I already need ::before and ::after for something else. Is there a css-way to change content on the tag itself?
Edit: Someone requested my current html and css, there you are..


input[type="checkbox"]
{
  appearance:none;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
    <body>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </body>
 </html>




There isn't a Unicode emoji for an unchecked checkbox, unfortunately (but there is a non-emoji pair, they aren't pretty) - so I don't recommend doing this.

@Dai there is ☐ ☑ ☒.  And in this case, it is for a menu, so the unchecked state would me no mark at all.

Please edit your post to show your current HTML+CSS.

You said you need ::before and ::after for something else - well, we kinda need to see that in your posted code in order for us to help you with finding alternatives to syle your checkbox without those psuedoelements.

don't post a random sample code simply to have a code in your question. Share the real code you are using (that also show your effort doing what you are trying to do)

What element are the before and after being used on (it cannot be input so there is quite a bit of missing code that might be relevant)

Try this. Note the comments.


document.querySelector(".checkbox-container").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let checked = document.querySelector(".example").checked;
  let label = document.querySelector(".check-text");
  // Pick your own unicode character if you want to
  if (checked) label.textContent = "\u2610";
  else label.textContent = "\u2705";
  // Use value depending on how you want to process input
  document.querySelector(".example").checked = !checked;
})
.example {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox-container {
  display: inline;
  /* optional */
  cursor: default;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="checkbox-container">
    <input type="checkbox" class="example" checked=false>
    <label class="check-text"> &#9989; </label>
  </div>
  <label>Awesome checkbox</label>
</body>

</html>




You don't need any JS to implement this - you can do it using only CSS with the :has() and :checked selectors.

Also, let checked = document.querySelector(".example").checked (since you're using class selector) - can lead to false positives if multiple such elements are present in the DOM...

Also <label> is closed with </p> instead of </label>, and also that's an incorrect use of HTMLLabelElement. You either wrap INPUT in LABEL, or use the for="" attribute.
